# How to work properly with async operations in nodejs streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stream

Recently I started to think - do I handle async operations inside Nodejs stream in a right way? Therefore I just want to make sure it's so.

```
class AsyncTransform extends Transform {
   constructor() { 
      super({objectMode: true});
   }

   public async _transform(chunk, enc, done) {
      const result = await someAsyncStuff();
      result && this.push(result);
      done();
   }
}
```

This small example works great, but basically, all async stuff takes some time for execution and in most cases, I want to work with chunks in parallel. I will put up `done` on the top of `_transform`, but this is not a solution for some reasons, and one of them is that fact that when the last chunk will invoke `done`, the next `push` will throw an error `Error: stream.push() after EOF`. So we can't make a push if the last chunk has already invoked with its `done`.

For handle this case I use the `_flush` transform's method in conjunction with chunk's queue counter (increase when it come in, decrease on `push`). God damn, there are already so many words, so here is just a sample of my code.

```js
const minute = 60000;
const second = 1000;

const CRITICAL_QUEUE_POINT = 50;

export class AsyncTransform extends Transform {

    private queue: number = 0;

    constructor() {
        super({objectMode: true});
    }

    public async _transform(chunk, enc, done) {

        this.checkQueue()
            .then(() => this.init(chunk, done));
    }

    public _flush(done) {
        this._done(done, true);
    }

    private async init(chunk, done) {
        this.increaseQueueCounter();
        this._done(done);

        const user = await new UserRepository().search(chunk);

        this.decreaseQueueCounter();
        this._push(user);
    }

    /**
     * Queue
     * */
    private checkQueue(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const _checkQueue = () => {
                if (this.queue >= CRITICAL_QUEUE_POINT) {
                    return setTimeout(_checkQueue, second * 10);
                }

                resolve();
            };

            _checkQueue();
        });
    }

    private increaseQueueCounter(): void {
        this.queue++;
    }

    private decreaseQueueCounter(): void {
        this.queue--;
    }

    /**
     * Transform API
     * */
    private _push(user) {
        this.push(user);
    }

    private _done(done, isFlush: boolean = false) {
        if (!isFlush) {
            return done();
        }

        if (this.queue === 0) {
            return done();
        }

        setTimeout(() => this._done(done, isFlush), second * 10);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it two years ago and was looking for a solution - a framework of some sort. I found a couple frameworks - highland and event stream - but all were so complex to use that I decided to write a new one: [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet).

Now your code can be as simple as:

```
const {DataStream} = require('scramjet');

yourDataStream.pipe(new DataStream())
    .map(async (chunk) => {
         await checkQueue();
         return new UserRepository().search(chunk);
    });
```

Or, if I understand the checkQueue() correctly it just keeps the simultaneous number of connections below the critical level, then it's even simpler like this:

```
yourDataStream.pipe(new DataStream({maxParallel: CRITICAL_QUEUE_POINT }))
    .map(async (chunk) => new UserRepository().search(chunk));
```

It will keep the number of connections at a stable level (everytime there's a response it'll start a new thread).

Comment: thanks man, I definitely will try your solution, it looks great!

Comment: one more question, can i .pipe another async stream after .map ?

Comment: You can actually just use another .map - no need to pipe as in [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet#example).

Of course you can still use pipe and even send to other streams.